# Execute performance test using benchmarkdotnet without generation a solution(.sln) file in .netcore

Tags: c#, benchmarkdotnet

I have a dotnet core project without a .sln file. I had added a benchmark test using nuget package benchmarkdotnet. But the performance result is giving error unable to find .sln file. Is there any alternative to run the benchmark without generation of .sln file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want a .sln file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to use  BenchmarkDotNet packet for dotnet, not dotnet core - so for different runtime environment. 
Please remove reference (or dependency) from project and try to install from nuget by typing

```
Install-Package BenchmarkDotNet.Core
```